# Chrome Extension - Javascript Origins for Google API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

I'm trying to make my Chrome extension upload files to Google Drive, but I'm stuck on authorization. I've been working off the code and instructions from [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js), but I don't know what to set for the "Authorized JavaScript Origins" in the developer console.

When I attempt to authorize, the origin is "chrome-extension://[extension id]", but this is not allowed as an authorized origin in the console.

What origin can I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to worry about the origin part in Chrome Extension, you simply need to generate a client id specific to the Chrome Extension, and use the [Chrome Identity API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity) to get authorization from the user.