# chrome extension authentication identity api

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

Hi i am developing a chrome extension and i need to authenticate user based on Google Plus account. I have implemented with Oauth 2.0 . But there is some issue when i execute

`chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }`

There is no popup window appears for authentication and i checked ***chrome://identity-internals/***. ***Token Status   Not Found*** for my extension.

I have followed all the steps for Chrome identity api and User authentication process

The Application id of my extension is same as in Api Credentials (Console.developer.google)

I have copied my Public key in manifest.json

But still no hope . i manually tried ***chrome.identity.getAuthToken*** in extension background page i got this error

`Unchecked runtime.lastError while running identity.getAuthToken: OAuth2 not granted or revoked.`

Ill paste my code here

Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Tinpack",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "tabs",
    "https://accounts.google.com/*",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["scripts/background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "images/icon.png",
      "38": "images/icon.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Tinpack",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "my client id"
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
    ]
  },
  "key": "my public key"
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://apis.google.com/; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Background.js

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
  'interactive': true
}, function(token) {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    alert("Error");
  } else {

    console.log(token);
    alert(token);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a small mistake. The Id created in Chrome webStore Dashboard should be same as the ID given in the Oauth Conset Screen .

Comment: But there is no ID in Oauth Consent Screen -  We have to provide app id when we create credentials - I am facing a loop - when I try to implement this